# Useful Non-System Procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Still rather new to SQL Server and learning as much as I can!

I have been looking over great system stored procedures and documenting when and where to use them. It brought me to a question I thought I would ask here!

What are some good non-system stored procedures you find yourself using or handy to have around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not stored procedures, but really useful queries to have at hand:

- [Glenn Berry's performance tuning queries](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/sql-server-2008-r2-diagnostic-information-queries-feb-2013/) - constantly updated and expanded
- [Michelle Ufford's Index Defrag Script](http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/)
- [Adam Machanic's Who Is Active](http://whoisactive.com)
- [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) scripts
- [Just about anything index-related](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/) that Kimberly Tripp (*The Queen of Indexing*) publishes on her blog
- [Almost all the scripts Paul Randal publishes](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/) on his blog, too

Comment: Thanks marc_s! I meant to include queries, functions etc that you find useful

Answer (score 2):

No SPROCS either, but I like the

[having-clause-tricks](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/9780080557526/group-characteristics/ch12lev1sec3) by [Joe Celko](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko), you find in his book "[Thinking in Sets](http://www.amazon.de/Joe-Celkos-Thinking-Sets-Management/dp/0123741378)".